# Batch code for uncompiling python

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation

This code (stored in a batch file) should take all the [*name*].pyc(that is a compiled Python file) in the directory, uncode it and put the result into a [*name*].txt **:**

```
@echo off
cd [directory]
for %%a in ("*.pyc") do (
uncompyle6  %%a > %%a.txt
)
pause
```

Of this program I don't like 3 things **:**

- The output name is something like [*name*].pyc.txt and I would like to be something like [*name*].txt ;
- Uncompyle6 give some statistic line as comment(# at the beginning), that I would like not to have on the final .txt file ;
- I would like that the .bat use the directory in which is stored for the cd command on line 2.

How can I fix these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
for %%a in ("*.pyc") do (
uncompyle6  %%a > %%~na1.txt
findstr /V "#" %%~na1.txt > %%~na.txt
del %%~na1.txt
)
pause
```

I tried by picking different pieces from various program I found online and I arrived to a solution that make what I wanted, if it's usefull for someone here is the solution.